# Redux Framework disable issue

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I am using redux framework plugin.I am add a setting using its default theme settings.setting is completely running.

But when I deactivate a plugin, my content will not be visible.

What should be done to prevent this from happening?

and, content is not to show in front side. why ?

I am using Simple Code see here attached screenshot( reduxissue.png ).

**Note : When I do plugin disable, front-end side does not show me my tittle.**

[image]

Comment: Replace `$global $redux_demo;` with `$redux_demo = get_option( 'redux_demo' );` and check the above.

Comment: @itzmekhokan Thank you, If I code accordingly it works.But I have stuck it like this everywhere in my theme.So you can find another solution Or you can create a function.